# Backup and restore windows partition on macbook

Tags: mac, partitioning, backup, boot-camp

I know there's lots of posts and talks on the subject, however I could not find some answers yet.

I'd like to do a backup of a bootcamp windows partition on macbook and restore it. I know there are tools like WinClone, but I'd like to learn more by doing things more manually.

I know you can copy Windows partition to a .dmg image via disk utility. I also know you can create a partition via disk utility and restore the .dmg into it.

Could you please help me understand how can you make the restored partition bootable during mac reboot via holding down 'option' key?

Thanks

Comment: It's no longer a good option to use the Hybrid MBR. Can you find out if your macbook has UEFI (2.0) firmware or EFI (1.1) firmware? The newer ones have UEFI, and older ones EFI.

Comment: How can I find out that? My Macbook is Air mid-2011

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but... I thought Carbon Copy Cloner may have been able to do it, but apparently not - they also recommend WinClone.
From their FAQ...

> CCC will not create a bootable backup of your Windows volume. Creating a bootable backup of OS X is mostly trivial. For Windows, there are numerous tweaks that have to be made — you must update the boot sector of the root target device to point to the correct start sector of NTFS volume, the boot.ini may need to be updated with the slice number of the partition, you have to restore the MBR, you must synchronize the GPT and MBR partition tables. Windows Vista+ has yet more requirements.

Comment: It's not so onerous to make a bootable backup, this is like making an excuse.

Comment: @MilindR - then please supply an answer explaining how, as that's what the OP wanted.